Modifying the column of a dataframe based in some rules
Suppose that I have a data frame as follows:
idp<-sort(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),10))
a1<-c(1,1,1,2,3,4,3,4,2,2)
a2<-c(3,3,NA,NA,4,1,2,3,1,1)
a3<-c(NA,NA,1,1,2,2,4,NA,NA,1)
a4<-c(4,3,2,1,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3)
dat<-data.frame(idp,outcome=c(a1,a2,a3,a4))

In dat, the idp is an identification of a person. Each value of a1, ..., a4 represents a status, where 4 indicates "dying"/death.
For any idp, if a 4 occurs all following values need to be set to 4. If NA occurs, we assume that the immediate previous state, which is not NA, should replace the NA. Finally, if the sequence starts with NA, then we should choose the immediate non-missing first state appearing in the vector.

Based on the data that you provided, what is your expected output?

Split based on idp, fill NAs, then find 4 and fill with 4 if any:
#split per idp and loop
l <- lapply(split(dat$outcome, dat$idp), function(i){
  # fill NA
  out <- zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(i, na.rm = FALSE),
                      na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)
  # fill 4 if any
  ix4 <- min(which(out == 4))
  if(length(ix4) > 0){ out[ ix4:length(out) ] <- 4 }
  
  out
  })


l
# $A
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 4 4 4
# 
# $B
# [1] 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
# 
# $C
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 4 4 4 4
# 
# $D
# [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

Convert back to dataframe
head(cbind(dat, outcomeNew = unlist(l, use.names = FALSE)), 10)
# convert back to dataframe
#    idp outcome outcomeNew
# 1    A       1          1
# 2    A       1          1
# 3    A       1          1
# 4    A       2          2
# 5    A       3          3
# 6    A       4          4
# 7    A       3          4
# 8    A       4          4
# 9    A       2          4
# 10   A       2          4


as an alternative using dplyr:

First group() the dataset by idp, to allow the computations be done by individual
Create additional column using mutate() that indicates the observation number where the state equals 4, as an intermediary helper variable.
In the mutate() step, overwrite values in the outcomecolumn for the observation numbers that are greater than the value of the intermediary helper variable.
Using mutate(), use na.locf from the zoo package to carry the last non NA observation forward
Finally, use na.locf again to fill the leading NA values with the first appearing non NA value.
you can remove the intermediary helper variable from the dataset if you no longer need it.

library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

#apply the rules 
dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(idp) %>%
  mutate(x = which(outcome == 4)[1], #creatae helper variable indicating observation number where state == 4
         outcome_new = case_when(
           row_number() >= x ~ 4, 
           TRUE ~ outcome
         )) %>%
  mutate(outcome_new = na.locf(outcome_new, na.rm = F)) %>% 
  mutate(outcome_new = na.locf(outcome_new, na.rm = F, fromLast = T)) %>%
  select(-x)
dat

Output
   idp   outcome outcome_new
   <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 A           1           1
 2 A           1           1
 3 A           1           1
 4 A           2           2
 5 A           3           3
 6 A           4           4
 7 A           3           4
 8 A           4           4
 9 A           2           4
10 A           2           4
11 B           3           3
12 B           3           3
13 B          NA           3
14 B          NA           3
15 B           4           4
16 B           1           4
17 B           2           4
18 B           3           4
19 B           1           4
20 B           1           4
21 C          NA           1
22 C          NA           1
23 C           1           1
24 C           1           1
25 C           2           2
26 C           2           2
27 C           4           4
28 C          NA           4
29 C          NA           4
30 C           1           4
31 D           4           4
32 D           3           4
33 D           2           4
34 D           1           4
35 D          NA           4
36 D          NA           4
37 D          NA           4
38 D           1           4
39 D           2           4
40 D           3           4


Or use https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html with "downup".

@zx8754 I did noticed it myself and was editing my post. It should work now.
